# AngularJS / JQuery - form input without an associated label

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have a problem with "Form input without an associated label". This appears on [textarea], [select], [select], [input] classes.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<form name="f" data-ng-submit="addTodo()">
  Nazwa:
  <textarea class="form-control" name="newTodo" data-ng-model="formData.newTodo" required></textarea>
  Typ:
  <select class="form-control" name="type" data-ng-model="formData.type" data-ng-option="value.name for value in categories" required></select>
  Estymowany czas:
  <select class="form-control" name="estimates" data-ng-model="formData.estimates" data-ng-option="value + 'h' for value in [] | rangeTime:9:true" required></select>
  Data:
  <input class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="formData.date" data-ng-data-picker="" name="date" required readonly="readonly">
  <br />
  <button class="btn btn-success" data-ng-disabled="f.$invalid">Add <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
</form>
```

Thanks for help!

> **Moderator Clarification:** The quoted message stated above is a warning provided by JetBrains products within the IDE. The OP is most likely using either
>   WebStorm or IntelliJ for front-end development.

Comment: What are you talking about? Where you see that message and when?

Comment: The msg appears while I set the cursor on :
<textarea class> 
<select class> <input class>

Comment: You mean in your IDE? If so what IDE? Please give full and correct details, don't have us squeeze the information out of you bit by bit.

Comment: dfsq answered the question. The problem disappeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an error, however it's recommended to associate labels with corresponding form elements for the sake of UX convenience. For example for the name field:

```
<label for="name">Nazwa:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="name" name="newTodo" data-ng-model="formData.newTodo" required></textarea>
```

I assume your IDE is smart enough to identify missing labels and provide you with a reasonable suggestion to add those.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `WebStorm`?

just follow the advice and add the label.
`label` is useful especially for `radio`, `checkbox` so that you can active them by merely clicking on the label.